# Edit file until the selected port will be not used by another application

Tags: bash, while-loop, port

I wrote a simple script that asks a user to edit the file until the moment when the user will enter the unused port. But it doesn't work (

```
while ! nc -z localhost $port; do
echo port is already used. Please choose another one.; read -p "Press enter to edit configuration file"; nano config.env;
done
```

$port it is an environment that the script takes from the current configuration file.
While loop doesn't start at all.
I have tried to run the script with ! and without ! the result is the same, looks like something wrong with the condition expression.

Comment: Do you have carriage returns on the config file? The loop starts here, but with errors which is expected from your script. I can't reproduce what you're describing.

Comment: I have solved the problem changing while to until, so the correct form would be:
`until ! nc -z localhost $port; do`
Kind of strange why it doesn't work with the while version 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test your scenario, I started an Apache httpd server on my laptop.  It listens on port 80.  Therefore `nc -z localhost 80` will exit with status code 0.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

port=80

while nc -z localhost $port
do
    echo "Port is already used. Please choose another one."
    read -p "Press enter to edit configuration file or CTRL-C to terminate."
    /usr/bin/nano config.env
    wait
    echo ""
done
```

- To simplify, I set port to 80 statically in my script.  Your version would read the port from config.env
- When the user presses enter, the `read` completes, and the editor is called.
- While the user edits the file, you want the script to `wait`.  So until the editor is closed, the script does nothing.  No point checking again for the port anyway.
- When the editor is closed, wait is done and another loop starts.
- I added "or CTRL-C to terminate" to give the user an out of the loop and the script.
- For readability, you should put your commands on separate lines.  Long series of commands on a single line, separated by `;` can be confusing, and it serves no purpose.  Carriage returns are not expensive :)